# Error after variable used as a function parameter in C?

Tags: c++, function, parameters

Can I use a variable as a function parameter after creating the variable while creating the function in C++ or another programming languages?

For example something like below. The code gets error but I wonder if it is possible to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a = 0;
int dondur(a){
    return a;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int b=20;
    cout << dondur(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you please rephrase your question? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: No, you cannot do that. The closest thing to what I guess you want is to declare your parameter normally and call as `dondur(a = b)`.

Answer (score 1):

Up to the fact, that your function should read

```
int dondur(int a){
    return a;
}
```

this is legal. The parameter 'int a' hides the global variable. The expected output is therefore 20 and the global variable a=0 remains unchanged.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you for your feedback; I removed the last sentence. Whether or not such uses are confusing depends on context and in fact is good practice in some places. Having vague names, such as 'a' in the global namespace might be ill advised, though.